# Match a pattern in vim, not in the beginning of line

Tags: regex, vim

I am trying to search a pattern in vim, but the pattern must not be in the beginning of line, aka the first non white space character of a line, for indentation purpose.

eg. :

```
    Should() not be found
    This() Should() be found
```

using `/Should`, both Should pattern are found.
I've tried to use something like, "not start of line" , but it is not working : `/[^^] *Should`. I've made it work using this : `/\w.* *Should`, but it is clearly not ideal.

Comment: Note: There is a [dedicated site for vi & vim](http://vi.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `\zs` to set a start of a match after a non-blank character followed by blanks:

```
/\S\s*\zsShould
```

Comment: Minor nit: "positive lookbehind" would be the `\@<=` thing.  `\zs` just sets the start of match for replacement purposes, and it's usually simpler and more efficient than positive lookbehind.

Comment: works but it does not use the concept of sart of line, i willl wait a bit to see if someone come up with an answer.

Answer (score 6):

Using positive look-behind, asserting there is at least one non-space character somewhere before the match:

```
/\(\S.*\)\@<=Should
```

Comment: works but it does not use the concept of sart of line, i willl wait a bit to see if someone come up with an answer.

Comment: What do you mean? It matches exactly what you said you want to match. Start of the line is implicit. Did you test it? If it "works", then it is an answer (as is Birei's, that you said the same thing to. You can't use `^` directly because you want "first non-indent character", not real start of line.

Comment: @user1416930 You don't need the "concept of sart[sic] of line" here, it's implicit. Neither `\S` nor `.` can match a line break. As such, this pattern asserts that there must be a non-blank between the start of the line and the word `Should`. The same goes for Birei's answer.

Answer (score 1):

This uses a negative match on the start of line, which aligs with the OP's problem the best:

/^@